# Swift - Calling @IBAction from another method without parameter

Tags: swift, parameters

This is my first question and I would like to ask if anyone knows how to call a @IBAction button from another function
Here is an example of my code

```
@IBAction func button1(sender: UIButton) {
    super.viewDidLoad()   
}

@IBAction func customPage(sender: AnyObject) {
    super.viewDidLoad() 
}
```

and I would like to change the text of button 1 from the customPage Function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An IBAction receives an event from the interface builder.  What you are looking for is an IBOutlet which ties the UI element to a variable.  Control drag `button1` (that is: hold down ctrl and then drag) from the interface builder to the body of your navigation controller to create an IBOutlet and change it's state in the `customPage` function.

Comment: thanx for the reply (y)